# What's the difference between a hemisphere and a semisphere

Tags: synonyms, transatlantic-differences

Is there any difference between ***h***emisphere and ***s***emisphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference when describing a shape.

The origin of 'Hemi' is Greek, meaning half and 'Semi' is Latin.

I have never heard anyone using the word semisphere.  It appears in some dictionaries, but not all.

A similar question has been answered here: [Demi-,semi-,hemi- Usage with words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356565/demi-semi-hemi-usage-with-words)

Comment: It *is* in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175756?redirectedFrom=semisphere#eid). You must be thinking of some other Oxford dictionary, like NOAD.

Comment: Perhaps ODO @Laurel lotta people think it's the OED. ODO doesn't have semisphere

Comment: Thanks @Laurel and Clare.  I was using https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/

Comment: Yeah, @GoodJuJu that's referred to around here as the ODO (Oxford dictionary online)

Comment: @Clare, thank you for the clarification.  I have modified my answer to remove the 'OED' reference.